$V$ is finite-dimensional and $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are subspaces of $V$ with $\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3>2\dim V$. Prove that $V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3\neq\{0\}$.
I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Exercise 15 in Exercises 2C on p.49:
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are subspaces of $V$ with $\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3>2\dim V$. Prove that $V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3\neq\{0\}$.

I solved the above exercise.
But I don't like my ugly solution.
Please tell me a better solution.

My solution:
$\dim (V_1+V_2)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)$.
$\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)=\dim (V_1+V_2)+\dim V_3-\dim \left((V_1+V_2)\cap V_3\right)$.
From above two equations, we get $$\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim \left((V_1+V_2)\cap V_3\right).$$
$$\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim \left((V_1+V_2)\cap V_3\right)\\\leq\\\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim \left(V_1\cap V_3+V_2\cap V_3\right).$$
$$\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim \left(V_1\cap V_3+V_2\cap V_3\right)\\\leq\\\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim (V_1\cap V_3)-\dim (V_2\cap V_3)+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
So, $$\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)\\\leq\\\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim (V_2\cap V_3)-\dim (V_3\cap V_1)+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
$$\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\dim (V_1\cap V_2)-\dim (V_2\cap V_3)-\dim (V_3\cap V_1)+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)\\\leq\\\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3\\+\dim (V_1+V_2)-\dim V_1-\dim V_2\\+\dim (V_2+V_3)-\dim V_2-\dim V_3\\+\dim (V_3+V_1)-\dim V_3-\dim V_1\\+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
$$\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3\\+\dim (V_1+V_2)-\dim V_1-\dim V_2\\+\dim (V_2+V_3)-\dim V_2-\dim V_3\\+\dim (V_3+V_1)-\dim V_3-\dim V_1\\+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)\\=-(\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3)\\+\dim (V_1+V_2)+\dim (V_2+V_3)+\dim (V_3+V_1)\\+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
Therefore, we get $$\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)\\\leq\\-(\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3)\\+\dim (V_1+V_2)+\dim (V_2+V_3)+\dim (V_3+V_1)\\+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
So, $$2\dim V<\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3\\\leq\\-\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)\\+\dim (V_1+V_2)+\dim (V_2+V_3)+\dim (V_3+V_1)\\+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
So, $$2\dim V+\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)\\-\dim (V_1+V_2)-\dim (V_2+V_3)-\dim (V_3+V_1)\\<\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
So, $$0\leq 2\dim V-\dim (V_2+V_3)-\dim (V_3+V_1)<\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3).$$
So, $V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3\neq \{0\}$.


Let $\dim V =n$
$\dim\big(V_1+V_2\big)=\dim V_1 + \dim V_2 -\dim \big(V_1\cap V_2\big)\leq n$
$\implies n-\dim V_3\lt \dim V_1 + \dim V_2 - n\leq \dim \big(V_1\cap V_2\big)$
$ n- \dim \Big(\big(V_1\cap V_2\big)\cap V_3\Big)$
$\lt  \dim \big(V_1\cap V_2\big)+\dim V_3 - \dim \Big(\big(V_1\cap V_2\big)\cap V_3\Big)$
$=\dim\Big(\big(V_1\cap V_2\big)+V_3\Big)$
$\leq n$
$\implies 0\lt\dim \Big(V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3\Big)$

user8675309, Thank you very much for your elegant answer!
